# NSArray calculation

Tags: objective-c, arrays, sum

I have two classes called "Cart" & "StoreItem"

I need to calculate the price of all the items in the Cart class’s ‘items’ property. ‘items’ is an NSArray holding a list of instances of ‘StoreItem’

EDIT: Realised I didn't put the question in.

How would I go about doing this?

Right now I have:

```
-(int)price {
    StoreItem *myStoreItem = [[StoreItem alloc]init];
    for (NSString *myShopItem in _items){
        [myShoppingItem ]    
    }   
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Best of luck. Did you have a question? Possibly even code from your own attempts?

Comment: what is your question ?? And you have tagged this question to C ??

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
-(int) price {
  int totalPrice = 0;

  for (id item in items) {
    if ([id isInstanceOf: [StoreItem class]]) {
      totalPrice += [(StoreItem*)item price]
    }
  }
  return totalPrice;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner if you use Key-Value-Coding

```
NSNumber* sum = [items valueForKeyPath: @"@sum.price"];
```